# Doesn't go routine and the channels work in order of call?

Tags: go, goroutine

Doesn't go routine and the channels worked in the order they were called.

and go routine share values between the region variables?

**main.go**

```
var dataSendChannel = make(chan int)

func main() {
    a(dataSendChannel)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    
}

func a(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go b(dataSendChannel)
        c <- i
    }
}

func b(c <-chan int) {
    val := <-c
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

**output**

```
> go run main.go
0
1  
54 
3  
61 
5  
6  
7  
8  
9
```

Comment: Goroutines are independent. I admit I have no idea what your code should do or what output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Channels* are ordered.  *Goroutines* are not.  Goroutines may run, or stall, more or less at random, whenever they are logically *allowed* to run.  They *must* stop and wait whenever you force them to do so, e.g., by attempting to write on a full channel, or using a `mutex.Lock()` call on an already-locked mutex, or any of those sorts of things.

Your `dataSendChannel` is unbuffered, so an attempt to write to it will pause until some goroutine is actively attempting to read from it.  Function `a` spins off one goroutine that will attempt one read (`go b(...)`), then writes and therefore waits for at least one reader to be reading.  Function `b` immediately begins reading, waiting for data.  This unblocks function `a`, which can now write some integer value.  Function `a` can now spin off another instance of `b`, which begins reading; this may happen before, during, or after the `b` that got a value begins calling `fmt.Println`.  This second instance of `b` must now wait for someone—which in this case is *always* function `a`, running the loop—to send another value, but `a` does that as quickly as it can.  The second instance of `b` can now begin calling `fmt.Println`, but it might, mostly-randomly, not get a chance to do that yet.  The first instance of `b` might already be in `fmt.Println`, or maybe it isn't yet, and the second one might run first—or maybe *both* wait around for a while and a *third* instance of `b` spins up, reads some value from the channel, and so on.

There's no guarantee *which* instance of `b` actually gets into `fmt.Println` *when*, so the values you see printed will come out in some semi-random order.  If you want the various `b` instances to sequence themselves, they will need to do that somehow.